# overflow: auto does not work as expected

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I searched in Google and also on this site before but didn't found any solution for my problem.

I have a shoutbox on my page and a teamspeak viewer with a specific height for the outer div.

However, the scrollbars look terrible on our new design and I tried to remove them from the shoutbox and ts viewer, but they won't disappear.

The code from the shoutbox:

```
<div class="shoutboxBoxSidebar">
    <div id="shoutbox" class="shoutbox sidebar">
        <div class="shoutboxContent fadeOut asc">
            <ul id="shoutboxEntryList">
                <li class="shoutboxEntry" id="shoutboxEntry3936">
                <li class="shoutboxEntry" id="shoutboxEntry3935">
            </ul>
        </div>
....
```

So I added the following css declarations to #shoutbox:

```
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
```

And the following settings to .shoutboxContent:

```
overflow:auto;
```

It still does not work and I am out of ammo now ;(

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0xL3cn2/)

Hopefully someone can help me out of this.

Comment: Please provide fiddle link of your code thanks

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/o0xL3cn2/ 
Alternative check out http://cywa.eu and click on "Community". You will see the scrollbars on the teamspeak viewer for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at yout Teamspeak div (sourcecode from the page).

```
<div id="ts3viewer_1016944" style="height:350px; overflow:scroll;">
```

Definitions in the element-Tag a higher rated then the CSS. 
If you remote the style-property its working and looking better ;D

Comment: Yeah, I know. But it still won't work. Look at the screenshot took for you of the shoutbox: http://bit.ly/1zwdeJh

Comment: It works for the Teamspeak viewer. For your shoutbox, there have to be somerwhere a height-definition (for example in the js script for the shoutbox).

Comment: The right scrollbar is still there. overflow: auto hides the scrollbar until they will be needed, doesn't it?

Comment: @peoples you are right! But because the shoutbox has a limteted height the scrollbar is needed. You have to find the reason for the height limitation or short the output for the shoutbox.

Comment: Ahhhhh, okay now I am going to understand it. I read about a hight definition in other questions before, but I thought that a fixed height would hide the scrollbar. Mhh. Okay, I try to work around and will reply if needed. Thank you!